# Как отправить решеную капчу на сервер vk python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, aiohttp

пишу скрипт на python используя aiohttp и vk api.

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    while True:
        async with session.get(f'https://api.vk.com/method/{method}?user_id=1&message=hello&random_id=0&access_token={token}&v={v}') as response:
            text = await response.text()
```

Иногда получаю капчу, решить я ее могу, но как ее вернуть на на вк?

Comment: В документации написано как https://dev.vk.com/api/captcha-error

Answer (score 0):

Обратимся к [документации](https://dev.vk.com/api/captcha-error). Цитирую:

> Если возникает данная ошибка, то в сообщении об ошибке передаются также следующие параметры:
>
> - `captcha_sid` — идентификатор captcha.
> - `captcha_img` — ссылка на изображение, которое нужно показать пользователю, чтобы он ввел текст с этого изображения.
>
> В этом случае следует запросить пользователя ввести текст с изображения `captcha_img` и повторить запрос, добавив в него параметры:
>
> - `captcha_sid` — полученный идентификатор
> - `captcha_key` — текст, который ввел пользователь

---

Коротко: после решения капчи нужно повторить запрос с полем `captcha_sid`, которое было в ошибке, и `captcha_key`, решение капчи.

Comment: Добавлю от себя: В `aiohttp` можно передавать [поле `params`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.request), чтобы не изобретать велосипед с _f-string_. А ещё, возможно, вам помогут какие-то готовые решения в виде библиотек (например асинхронный [vkbottle](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/)).